# How to force addition when a value is missing in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, addition

I want to do an addition in a select statement like this:

```
select (I + j + k) as total from MyTable ...
```

As expected, if any of the I, j, k is null, total is returned as null.

How do I code this select so that when any of the I, j, k is null (missing), the missing value is considered 0 for the purpose of addition (so that total is never null)? Thanks.

Comment: either coalesce or have a default value of 0, not allowing nulls. if all values have 0 then it will work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT total = COALESCE(l,0) + COALESCE(j,0) + COALESCE(k,0)
FROM dbo.MyTable;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select ISNULL(I,0) + ISNULL(j,0) + ISNULL(k,0) as total from MyTable ...
```

or

```
select IFNULL(I,0) + IFNULL(j,0) + IFNULL(k,0) as total from MyTable ...
```

on mysql

Comment: No such thing as `IFNULL` in SQL Server. Maybe you meant `NULLIF` but that wouldn't make sense in this context.

Comment: Yeah, I was just going to add that is for mysql, you are to fast for me.

Comment: Not sure why a mysql answer belongs here - the question does not involve mysql.

Comment: Probably not, but he does have the sql tag

Comment: then shouldn't your answer provide an example for every single RDBMS on the planet?